# How to return a max value in a vector in R

Tags: r

```
stock.prices=c(21,25,23,22,32)

week.days=c("mon","tues","wed",thu","fri")

names(stock.prices)=week.days
```

1. To find stock prices that are greater than 24
2. To find the max stock price of the week

Why doesn't the second code work

```
stock.prices[stock.prices>24]

stock.prices[max(stock.prices)]
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but you're missing a quotation mark in week.days

Comment: Take a look at what `max(stock.prices)` returns - `25` - and then `stock.prices[1]` and `stock.prices[2]` and `stock.prices[25]`

Comment: Oh. I get it. It is geting the 25th index of the stock.prices vector.

Comment: > What would be the best way to return the max price and week day

Comment: @JohnDoe `max(stock.prices)` or `which.max(stock.prices)` if you need the index.

Comment: Awesome. thank you. I have another solution from the MOOC which says.... stock.prices[stock.prices==max(stock.prices)]

Comment: Yes, `which.max()` is basically a shortcut to do `stock.prices[stock.prices == max(stock.prices)]`, either works.

Comment: @Marius yes but no. It will only return a single index even if multiple values equal the max. So it won't always give the same result.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This was my first post. And was very happy with the community support. Thanks a ton.